# Is there a way to write a function to call multiple times in java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void platformAdminLogin() {
    // login as platform admin with correct credentials
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailId")).sendKeys("platform.admin@rotic.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.className("loginButton")).click();
        System.out.println("Sucessful login as Platform admin");
        //Logout
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("headerIconLogout")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("logOutYesIcon")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while login as Platform admin = " + e);
    }
```

How to write a function for logout and how to call multiple times

Comment: @Test(invocationCount = 10) you can use. It will execute your same test case 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function using any iterator such as *while* or *for* loops and set your calling limit.

Comment: or also, you can used multi-threading to call your function

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function with a time duration using the java scheduler
[schedulers-in-java](https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Write method like this below with name as "logOut", then in you Test function you can call this method when you want script to logout

```
public void logOut(){
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("headerIconLogout")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("logOutYesIcon")).click();

}
@Test(priority = 0)
public void platformAdminLogin() {
    // login as platform admin with correct credentials
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailId")).sendKeys("platform.admin@rotic.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.className("loginButton")).click();
        System.out.println("Sucessful login as Platform admin");
        
//Calling Logout method Here       
       logOut();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while login as Platform admin = " + e);
    }
```